# "go back" vs "come back" - why use one rather than the other?

Tags: present-tense

I think these two sentences are the same. I looked up "go back" and "come back" in the dictionary, and both mean "back to". So is there a difference between them? I don't understand why the writer would choose to express the sentence one way, rather than the other. Is there a reason I am not aware of?

> He wants to **go back** to his wife and children, but he doesn't dare.
>
> He wants to **come back** to his wife and children, but he doesn't dare.

Comment: Am I missing something here? If a husband and father *wants* to go/come back to his family, he must *care*. If he didn't care, he wouldn't want to go back.

Comment: It is dare, note care :)

Comment: Oh, right. my bad.

Comment: By the way, are there many more of these two sentences questions? You could attempt to explain what you don't understand.

Comment: OK. I will try. I am just reading some texts and cannot fully understand them, as I don't understand why they are expressed in this way, rather than other. What is wrong with this type of questions? As far as I know this site is intended to help English learners.

Comment: Because it seems to me that you're capable of explaining what you don't understand. Have you tried looking the expressions up in a dictionary? Did they have the same definitions?

Comment: Of course I have tried, Both have the same meaning, which is "Back to"

Comment: @VardanHovhannisyan These are the kind of statements we would like you to include in your question. It helps give us a starting point on where to answer. "I think these two sentences are the same. I looked up "go back" and "come back" in the dictionary, and both mean "back to". So is there a difference between them? I don't understand why they would choose to express the sentence one way, rather than the other." THAT would be a great question--and in fact, I'm going to edit this question for you, so that it will be better received.

Comment: "Yes or no" questions are not acceptable on ELL. But "why can't I say X instead of Y, here's my research and here's why I don't understand..." That's a good question. Please try to include as much context and research as possible! See this post: [Details, Please](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are grammatical and idiomatic, but have slightly different meaning. In the second one, the speaker is in some way identifying with the wife and children, or where they are: probably implying that they and the speaker are in the same community which "he" is currently outside.

This is a systematic difference betwen "go" and "come" in English: "come" almost always means to somewhere associated with the speaker. Canonically it means to where the speaker is now, but it might be to where the speaker is going to be when the subject arrives, or it might be to the speaker's home, or the speaker's town, even if the speaker is not there or not going to be there.

Answer (score 4):

English is so wishy-washy about directions, at least, compared with other languages. *In general* consider the perspective from the person speaking, or the person being spoken about.  For example, if I say:

> "He wants to come back to Miami"

implies that *I'm* in Miami, or I'm talking from the perspective of someone in Miami.

> "'I'll come back to you someday, John!' she cried, waving from the window of the departing train."

The woman is thinking of this from John's perspective, some future time when he sees her coming.

In your example, the first sentence seems pretty straightforward.  In the second sentence, the person talking is thinking from the perspective of the wife and children, and so it implies some degree of familiarity with the family.

But as I said, this is general use.  Sometimes people will use one or the other interchangeably, whichever feels more comfortable.

Comment: If you want the details (not really wishy-washy, just weird) about directions, look at Fillmore's [Deixis Lectures](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/Deixis.html), specifically [Lecture 2, 'Space'](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/2-Space.pdf), as well as [Lecture 5, 'Coming and Going'](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/5-ComingAndGoing.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

> He wants to go back to his wife and children, but he doesn't dare.
>
> He wants to come back to his wife and children, but he doesn't dare.

In these sentences, neither *he* nor *his mother* is the speaker or the listener. So to choose between the first and second sentences you have to decide from whose viewpoint you are looking at the situation:

If you are looking at it from *his* point of view, it will be

> He wants to *go back* to his wife and children, but he doesn't dare.

If you take *his wife's* viewpoint, it will be

> He wants to *come back* to his wife and children, but he doesn't dare.

Anyway, both the sentences mean the same thing and I fully agree with @Andrew that it's utterly up to the one who's expressing the idea to make the choice.